# How to get away with a murder

Tags: logical-deduction, situation

Someone is about to be executed because he killed someone and he is asked how he wants to die by a strange question:

> If you say something true now, you will be executed with electricity, if you say something false you will be executed with a gun.

Then our guy says something and they could not kill him.

> What could he say?

Comment: Is it something troll like "The power just went out"

Comment: @thecoder16 then I would add lateral-thinking tag for it :)

Comment: Have you ever noticed how similar the puzzling.se logo is to workplace.se? Especially when shrunk down for the HNQ sidebar.

Comment: @immibis [yep](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4748/18250)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil And specifically what it looks like when you see a question from workplace.se about how to get away with murder...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He says

> **"I will be killed with a gun"**

So:

> If the statement is true he should be killed with electricity, making it false.
>
> If it is false he will be killed with a gun, making it true.
>
> Hence it is a paradox and they let him go as the statement can be neither true or false.

Alternatively as @sousben points out, he could say

> 'You will not kill me with electricity' - which is the logical reverse of the other statement and therefore does the same

Comment: oops i was overthinking it way too much

Comment: @thecoder16 hehe I liked your answer though :P

Comment: it could have been "this sentence is a lie" or similar

Comment: @ALinuxLover that works too.

Comment: They might just throw him back in his cell rather than execute him.

Comment: @jpmc26 of course but the puzzle just says they did not kill him

Comment: Er, I meant rather than release him ("let him go"). xD

Comment: @jpmc26 Anyone who comes up with this is the situation I think deserves to be released :P